# Devise, multiple Models and ApplicationCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I needed to add support for multiple models (tables with users) to the application. In general, everything went well with the exception of ApplicationCable.

The app has this code:

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This code is quite popular. It is present in many sources.

But it doesn't work in cases where multiple models are required. Connections on the front-end are cut off due to:

> An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected

**UPD:**

I realized that I can use an explicit indication:

```
env['warden'].user(:admin)
```

But now I don't understand how to determine this automatically for the ApplicationCable connection.

---

Can you please tell me how you can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user(:admin)
        verified_user
      elsif verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```